# In Lyx, how to change the "Part" section to "Chapter"?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, lyx

I am using the default Lyx document "article".

My sections range from "Part" to "Subsubsection". When I compile my pdf, I would like to replace "**Part** 1 Title1", "Part 2 Title2", etc by "**Chapter** 1 Title1", "Chapter 2 Title2", etc. Any idea how to do that? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You could just use a document class that provides chapters, like `report` or `book`.

Comment: You could add the following LaTeX code to your preamble: `\renewcommand{\partname}{Chapter}`. Or better take Werner's advice.

Comment: Thank you both of you for your help. The problem with Werner's solution is that, when you have numerous child's documents, you have to change the document class for all of them. I have done it though and it keeps showing Part 1, Part 2, etc. ! :(  I have also tried lockstep's suggestion, but it doesn't make a difference either. Is there like a "force" command to replace "Part" by "Chapter"...?

Comment: Here is my preamble:

Comment: \newcommand{\sq}{\footnotesize}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand{\partname}{Chapter}

\renewcommand*\thepart{\arabic{part}}  % arabic numbers for part
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{section}{part}  % reset section number when a new part starts
\makeatother
\renewcommand*\thesection{\thepart.\arabic{section}}  % section 1.1
\renewcommand*\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}} % subsection 1.1.1

Answer (score 5):

As you are using LyX this mean that by default you are using `babel` package too (for things like that always is a must a MWE). So you need some like this in the preample:

```
\addto\captionsenglish{%
  \renewcommand{\partname}%
    {Fake Chapter}%
}
```

**However**, Lyx will put the `babel` package  **after** the `\makeatletter` --`\makeatother` chunk in your code (see the complete source in the View menu), and therefore cannot work.

**Hence, you need  put also `\usepackage{babel}` before**  in the preamble, to obtain a file that work as this MWE:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\addto\captionsenglish{%
  \renewcommand{\partname}%
    {Fake Chapter}%
}
\begin{document}
\part{Some part or chapter}
The \textbackslash{}thepart{} is \thepart{} and the  \textbackslash{}partname{} is \partname{}

That is all. 
\end{document}
```

Or deactivate `babel` through Lyx menus and put only `\renewcommand{\partname}{Fake Chapter}` in the preamble.