# In Lyx, how to change "Part I" with some other text

Tags: sectioning, formatting, lyx

I'm using the article class. When creating a new part, I would like to change "Part 1" to "Experiment 1", "Part 2" to "Experiment 2" and so on, followed by my part title. How can I do that?

I've found this question, but the answers didn't work for me
[In Lyx, how to change the "Part" section to "Chapter"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69457/in-lyx-how-to-change-the-part-section-to-chapter)

Thank you! :)

Edit:
This is my preamble:

```
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\date{}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setlength{\headheight}{15.2pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\lhead[]{}
\rhead[]{}
\lhead[]{}
\rhead[]{}
\lfoot[\thepage]{}
\rfoot[]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\partname}{Experiment}%added later
```

EDIT:
The `\renewcommand{\partname}{Experiment}` line works fine with the language set to English, but i need to make this work in other languages, because now if I add the toc it's called "Contents", while I need an italian "Indice".

Edit:
self-answer (for all who may find this helpful): use `\renewcommand\contentsname{Indice}` to change "Content" to "Indice" or whatever.

Comment: Have you tried `\renewcommand{\partname}{Experiment}`?

Comment: In the preamble right? It doesn't work...
I've added my preamble in the question.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: See if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119117/translate-paragraph-environment helps.

Comment: Thank you Werner and @Corentin!
The preamble code works but I had to set the language to english first (I had it set to italian).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

LyX just provides an interface (or front end) to LaTeX. So, while you may see

> **Part I  Some text**

as your title inside the editor view, the LaTeX code associated with it

```
\part{Some text}
```

will output

> **Experiment I  Some text**

if you add

```
\renewcommand{\partname}{Experiment}
```

to your preamble (Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble). If you wish to change this in the editor as well (so the visual matches the PDF output), you need to edit the `stdsections.inc` layout file; specifically the part style:

```
Style Part
  Category               Section
  Margin                 Dynamic
  LabelString            "Part \thepart"
  LabelType              Counter
  ...
```

You would have to update `LabelString` to read `"Experiment \thepart"` instead.

Comment: it does not work for me... my document language is English, so this is not the problem. do you know what it is?

Comment: @bobsacameno: You should provide enough information so one can replicate your issue. I can't with just the statement you provided.

Comment: sorry, I thought it was a common issue that an obvious fix is known. I have LyX Version 2.2.2 (10 October 2016), on a Mac. My TeX distribution is Full TeX Live 2015 Distribution V271. What other information should I provide?

Comment: It works due to this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119117/translate-paragraph-environment, by adding `\AtBeginDocument{% ... }` to wrap the command in this answer.

Comment: Is it possible to update the view in the editor by adding a line to a custom `my.layout` file instead of changing `stdsections.inc`? Like an override?

Comment: @Nick: I'm sufficiently unfamiliar with LyX setup to not know whether that's possible or not. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the babel settings for your language, in your case is italian so an example is:

\addto\captionsitalian{%
\renewcommand{\partname}%
{Volume}%
}