# babel somehow interfering with \partname?

Tags: babel, parts

This doesn't make any sense to me, but for some reason, `\usepackage{babel}` is causing `\partname` not to work as expected.

Here's a MWE. `\renewcommand{\partname}{}` should give an output text without the word "Pars"—just the Roman numeral and the name of the part. If I remove `babel`, it works fine.

Is there a way I can fix this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage{fontenc}[utf8]
\usepackage[english,main=latin]{babel}      

\renewcommand{\partname}{}

\begin{document}
\part{Pīrāta Veterānus}
\end{document}
```

Comment: at begin document babel sets everything up for the main language so latin here. You need to use the babel features to redefine the latin partname to empty, or do the simple overwrite after begin document so after babel has installed the latin version

Comment: Does it produce `\partname=PARS`? :-)

Comment: @Bernard It does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You modify the fixed word by doing

```latex
\addto\extraslatin{\renewcommand{\partname}{}}
```

Your attempt doesn't work, because `\begin{document}` issues `\selectlanguage{latin}`, which sets `\partname` to “Pars” unless modified.

However, this is not a particularly good way to remove the word, because it wouldn't remove the space.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,main=latin]{babel}

\addto\extraslatin{\renewcommand{\partname}[1]{}}

\begin{document}
\part{Pīrāta Veterānus}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Compare with the result if you just use `\renewcommand{\partname}{}`:

[image]

Sorry for the images with different size, but check the alignment and you'll see that in the latter picture the I is moved to the right.

The `book` class only uses `\partname` in the definition of `\@part`. This is however not guaranteed to work with other packages such as `titlesec`.

---

The line `\usepackage{fontenc}[utf8]` is meaningless. I changed it to `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

You possibly wanted to do `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, but this is no longer needed on recent TeX distributions.

Comment: Thank you so much (for both answers)!

Comment: In another document I did the same thing with chapters by adding \renewcommand{\chaptername}. Does that cause the same problem (not removing the space), and, if it does, what do you suggest as a solution?

Comment: @JoelDerfner Knowing the context would be important.