# Numbering of sections and subsections in LyX

Tags: sectioning, lyx

I am using LyX to write my thesis. I use the document class "article", and I really want to continue doing that.

The problem is the numbering of the sections/subsections.

If it is the x. section of chapter y, I want the numbering to be like

y.x

If it is the z. subsection of section x of chapter y, I want the numbering to be like

y.x.z

Is it possible in any way?

Comment: `article` doesn't have chapters. But take a look at Document --> Settings --> Numbering & TOC.

Comment: Sorry, I mean "part" instead of "chapters". I made the mistake because I use \renewcommand{\partname}{Chapter} in the preamble.

Comment: Ah, I see. Same as this question then? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69328/in-lyx-part-section-in-arabic-numbers-and-numbering-the-rest-of-the-sections

Comment: No problem. We'll close this question as a duplicate then.

Comment: Okay, but thanx.